# Remap keys in loops

Tags: autohotkey

Background: I'm trying to have a `f-mode` and `d-mode` which means if I press down the `f` key and press another key like `i` then nothing happens excepts a shortcut. let say it will send `Up` key instead of f and I.
Issue: how I can remap a pressed key (I in my example) to a shortcut (Up as example)?

Code:

```
d::
    f::{
        ;...
        loop{
            if !GetKeyState("f","p") && !GetKeyState("d","p"){
                break
            }
            if GetKeyState("i","p") {
                OutputDebug "i"
                send "{up}"
                continue
            }
            ; ...
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to make a custom combination.

From the [Docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo):

> You can define a custom combination of two keys (except joystick
> buttons) by using " & " between them. In the below example, you would
> hold down Numpad0 then press the second key to trigger the hotkey:
>
> ```
> Numpad0 & Numpad1::MsgBox You pressed Numpad1 while holding down Numpad0.
> Numpad0 & Numpad2::Run Notepad
> ```

But also note:

> The prefix key loses its native function: In the above example,
> Numpad0 becomes a prefix key; but this also causes Numpad0 to lose its
> original/native function when it is pressed by itself. To avoid this,
> a script may configure Numpad0 to perform a new action such as one of
> the following:
>
> ```
> Numpad0::WinMaximize A   ; Maximize the active/foreground window.
> Numpad0::Send {Numpad0}  ; Make the release of Numpad0 produce a Numpad0 keystroke. See comment below.
> ```

This is to prevent holding down a key from spamming inputs while you wait to press the second part of a key combination. So essentially, your 'f' and 'd' keys will now perform their normal functions when you release them instead of initially pressing them down.

---

Anyways, the code would become:

```
f & i::
d & i::
Send {Up}
return

f::f
d::d
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I started my solution with the way you recommended, but problem was when I typing a word like "first" f and i map to up. So I am trying to solve my problem manually with a loop.

Comment: Let me share my idea. I want to track input if `f↓f↑i↓` no matter how fast happened, maps to a normal type ie `fi` but when `f↓j↓` happens in less than 150ms,  maps to `up` as a shortcut. finally, `f↓` after 150ms starts mapping to `f`.

Comment: After spending some time testing different solutions, I found that when I press `f↓f↑i↓i↑` too fast in windows, I don't know why windows apps get the events in this order: `f↓i↓f↑i↑`. In Mac no matter how fast you type, the order of keys is the same as the order you press keys. I tested it with both my laptop's keyboard and an external keyboard the result was the same. Any idea?

Comment: So like an autorelease after 150 ms? This would stop you from doing things like holding down the 'f' key, but I think I could do that if that's what you need

Comment: No, autorelease is not my problem. Like I said in my last comment: My issue is when I quickly press `f` key down and release it then quickly press `i` key down and release it (`f↓f↑i↓i↑` very fast) the order of keys in AHK and other apps is: `f` key down, `i` key down, `f`key up, `i` key up (`f↓i↓f↑i↑`) which is not the order I press my keys. This looks like a hardware or Windows OS limitation.

Comment: Interesting... I don't really know what might be causing that. I think that you may have better luck asking the SuperUser People about this, since it seems to be more of a Windows OS question at this point.